# One to many vs Many to many relationship confusion?

Tags: database, hibernate, class, entity-relationship

I am trying to create a proper relationship on Hibernate and I have the following relationship between Recipe and Ingredients entities:

[image]

I thought that:

- One recipe can have multiple ingredients
- One ingredient can also be part of different recipes

In this situation, I would create **many to many** relationship.

**However**, by considering the `unit` and `amount` fields in the `Ingredient` entity, I think the amount of ingredient for a specific recipe may be changed later. In this situation, each ingredient should be belonging to a specific recipe. As a result, I create **one to many** relationship as shown on the image.

**1.** Is the approach (**one to many**) explained above true?

**2.** I also think that for a Category entity (that describes recipe categories e.g. vegetarian, diabetic, ...), I should use **many to many** relationship as the category is not identical for a specific recipe and when updating any category, all the related recipes should be affected. Is this true?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to map a many to many relationship, then you need a relationship table.

So your database tables will be

```
recipe <-> recipe_ingredient <-> ingredient
```

As you want to have attributes on the relationship amount and unit will then go to the recipe_ingredient table.

This will also result in three classes. Recipe, RecipeIngreident and Ingredient.

Comment: Hi Simon, thanks a lot for your reply. But my question is much more related to "what?" instead of "how?". So, I am not sure if I really need to use many-to-many relationship instead of one-to-many. Because, as I explained, if I add 50 gr Olive Oil for a recipe, it may not be used for another Recipe. Even if it is used, it may be updated for a recipe and then this will also changes another recipe that is using the same ingredient. So, could you re-read the point I mentioned in the question and clarify me if I need many-to-many or not?

Comment: This is a question of normalization. Read more here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

Answer (score 0):

The answer to both of your questions is yes. However, you should still consider many-to-many according to @Simon Martinelli's answer in this situation as you will eventually have many duplicate entries and data for `Olive Oil` across many different recipes which will only have unique IDs/Amounts/Units. However, this is just a suggestion and you are free to write your code however you wish.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I agree with you, **but** the point that I want to emphasize is that; For example, for a Mushroom Soup recipe, we have 50 ml Olive Oil. For a Cup Cake we have 50 ml Olive Oil. At first glance, it seems redundant. But, think of that we want to update the amount of Olive Oil to 30 ml for only Cup Cake. Then, the amount for Mushroom Soup will also be changed. In this scene, when considering the Amount and the Unit in the same Ingredient table, I think we should not use many to many relationship. Is that true?

Comment: If there is only name field for the Ingredient without amount and unit, it would be ok to use many to many. but here is a different scenario. I am wrong?